# Java Server Application - Facebook Automatic login and interaction

Tags: java, facebook, authentication

I am trying to use org.apache HttpClient and Facebook-API to create a server application.
It has to automatically login to facebook using the username and password provided into a configuration file.

In this application I know the application ID, the API_KEY and the SECRET. I also have, as I said, the username and the password.

For obvious reason (I have no user interface) I cannot use any integrated browser in my application.
My application should simply create a post on the user account wall when it is called, so basically when the application runs I have to perform the following steps:

- Login with the user credentials
- Post the message on the wall
- disconnect

At the moment I am facing the very first problem: the automatic login.
I read, looking on the web, that on Facebook the login can be done ONLY through a manual user action. I tried also to simulate a browser through the HttpClient of the org.apache library but I am always getting lost in some point.

So my first question is:
- Is it possible to automatically login through that kind of application?
- If the answer to the first question is yes, can someone provide some simple and clear tutorial on how to do it?

Thank you very much
Charlie

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this would be using the facebook Single Sign-on to your service before they can use whatever is triggering your server to post to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Facebook application, add your user to this application (by single sign-on) and make this user give full permissions to this application, by using OAuth. This way you will be able to use the Facebook API to do what you want to do.

Comment: This seems to be quite simple but unfortunately API are being changed very often and I didn't find any "clear" tutorial neither on the official forum nor in other places.

For example I didn't find anything about adding my user to the application using single sign on.

I am sorry but I am really new to Facebook development and this field seems to be very confused.

I just only need something like a step by step tutorial to log in into Facebook from a desktop application. All the examples I have found are not working and all of them have different screenshots than what I see in my Facebook App.